# Project Euler- Finding the divisors Problem 12

Tags: python, math

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

```
1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
```

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

```
 1: 1
 3: 1,3
 6: 1,2,3,6
10: 1,2,5,10
15: 1,3,5,15
21: 1,3,7,21
28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
```

We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

I tried the following, I have questions about math of the problem. Why my approach doesn't work or too slow ?

```
def triangularNumber(number):
    return number*(number+1)/2


def divisorsList(number):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        if(number%i == 0):
            divisors.append(i)
    return divisors

while(True):
    n = 10000
    x = int(triangularNumber(n))
    divisors = divisorsList(x)
    if (len(divisors)>500):
        print(x)
        break
    n += 1
```

Comment: your method of calculating divisors is very very slow.  you have to see that as n approaches 10 000 the triangular number is 10 ^ 8  /2 and you check divisors by counting to 10**8 for each number.

Comment: You could use a technique as described here: [Finding the number of divisors of n](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/m170/wk2/numdivisors.html) along with your solution to a previous problem ([3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3)) to get some improvements :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check divisors up to
   sqrt(number) and calculate the other divisor, i.e., if x divide n,
   then n/x is a divisor. However, this will probably ask for a sort in
   the end.
2. You can check question
   https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-divisors-of-any-number

Comment: Please include at least a summary of linked resources.